# Is there a plugin / something already built into Jekyll which can generate html tags?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

Hey guys is there a plugin I am missing or method I cannot find to use within Jekyll so I don't have to manually write a bunch of html tags?

Example would be {% a href="blah %}

This would render out

```
 <a href="blah"></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer is no, there's no stuff built in but there are provisions for you to [extend Jekyll for you needs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/). Unless, someone else knows better, I'm willing to be proven wrong. You have two options that I can think of though ...

**Option 1: Use markdown, it's built in**

Instead of what you are trying to do. Liquid (what you are using) doesn't seem to support `<a>` tags - [see here](http://docs.shopify.com/themes/liquid-basics/output#html) for more info from their docs

The GitHub guides provide details on how to use Markdown;

- [Mastering Mardown](http://guides.github.com/overviews/mastering-markdown/)
- [Markdown Basics](https://help.github.com/articles/markdown-basics)
- [GitHub Flavored Markdown](https://help.github.com/articles/github-flavored-markdown)

Though the above links are for GitHub, the apply on Jekyll as well since [Tom Preston-Werner](http://tom.preston-werner.com/) (co-founder of GitHub) is the guy who wrote Jekyll. Probably because it was born out of an internal need in GitHub, and figured there's no harm open-sourcing it.

Oh, and this might be better because, if you are using GitHub pages ... they don't run any custom scripts.

**Option 2: Write a custom tag**

There's some documentation in the official [Jekyll site](http://jekyllrb.com/) on [the plugin page](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/). Something like this:

```
# Define the custom tag, 'a_tag'
module Jekyll
  class RenderHyperlinkTag < Liquid::Tag

    def initialize(tag_name, text, tokens)
      super
      @url = text
    end

    # At a minimum, liquid tags must implement render which outputs
    # the contents of the tag
    def render(context)
      "<a href=\"#{@url}\"></a>"
    end
  end
end

# Register the new tag, 'a_tag'
Liquid::Template.register_tag('a_tag', Jekyll::RenderHyperlinkTag)
```

And you'd have something like this ...

```
<!-- Usage -->
{% a_tag 'http://example.com' %}

<!-- Output -->
<a href="http://example.com"></a>
```

I must admit, I haven't tested this just giving a high level explanation of what I'd try out from what I can garner from the docs. Try it out and see if it'll work and fix any errors that may spew out (I loosely typed this).

Comment: This isn't what I'm quite looking for. It's mostly similar to a rails tag helper that I can use in templates.

Comment: @amchang87 Updated the answer with a second option. Let me know how it goes.

Comment: I agree with option #2, I was just hoping someone had something out of the box before I had to start writing my own stuff, thanks.